# Instantiate NSView with custom objects in it using NSNib

Tags: swift, cocoa, instantiation, nsview

I have a subclass of `NSView` called `MyView`, and I have a nib file whose `File's Owner` is `MyView`. I would like to create copies of a view in my nib file, and so I am using a class function as shown below:

```
class MyView: NSView {

    @IBOutlet var myImageView: NSImageView! // Cocoa class
    @IBOutlet var myEditingField: EditingField! // Custom subclass of cocoa object

    class func initWithTitle(_ title: String) -> MyView {
        let myNib = NSNib(nibNamed: "MyView", bundle: nil)

        var myArray = NSArray()

        myNib!.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: &myArray) // instantiate view and put in myArray

        var myViewInstance = myArray[0] as! MyView

        myViewInstance.imageView.image = NSImage(named: title)
        myViewInstance.myEditingField.stringValue = title // this line

        return myViewInstance
    }

}
```

I have connected an `IBOutlet` from an `NSImageView` in the view in my nib file to the property `myImageView` in the `MyView` class, and I have connected an `IBOutlet` from an `EditingField`, a custom subclass of `NSTextField` that I wrote, to the `myEditingField` property. So, to create an instance of `MyView` simply I do:

```
let instance = MyView.initWithTitle("foo")
```

The issue with this method is that when `IB` creates the view, it is calling the required initializer `init(coder:)` on the `EditingField` in the view in the nib file. Originally, I had left my implementation of `init(coder:)` as simply the default `fatalError("init(coder:) is not implemented")` because I didn't think `IB` would call that initializer. I had figured `IB` would call `init(frame:)`, but in reality it does call `init(coder:)`. So, I tried implementing  `init(coder:)` the following way:

```
class EditingField: NSTextField {
    var id: String
    // ... other properties 

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        print("init coder")

        self.id = "default"
        // ... other properties get default values, just like id

       super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this did not work either. When I run the project using the above initializer in `EditingField`, the line `myViewInstance.myEditingField.stringValue = title` in `MyView` throws an error. When this happens, the debugger console reveals that the property `myEditingField` is nil, and, unlike `myImageView`, hasn't been initialized at all (despite the fact that the print message in `init(coder:)` still prints!)

So, my questions are (1) how do I initialize/create an `NSView` from a nib file that has custom objects in it? (2) why does `IB` call `init(coder:)` on `EditingField`? and (3) why is `myEditingField` nil despite the print message suggesting that the initializer ran?

Comment: 1. The File's Owner in the XIB should be the default class `NSObject`, not `MyView`. The XIB should contain one object, a view of class `MyView` and its properties are connected to its subviews. Change the name of the method to `viewWithTitle`, don't use "init…".

Comment: I changed the File's Owner to `NSObject`, and now `myEditingField` isn't nil anymore. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work because I'm getting the error "Failed to connect (myEditingField) outlet from (ViewInstantiate.MyView) to (ViewInstantiate.EditingField): missing setter or instance variable". This is weird because the Assistant Editor suggests that the `EditingField` in the `MyView` is in fact connected to the property.

Comment: Check the XIB for obsolete connections. Is `myEditingField` of the file's owner still connected?